# ¿Cómo puedo hacer MERGE en una misma tabla para insertar o dependiendo si el registro existe o no?

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert, transacciones

Estoy intentando hacer MERGE a una sola tabla pero no he tenido éxito. He investigado y la mayoría de veces he encontrado ejemplos de una tabla actualizada en base a otra. **Lo que yo quiero hacer es actualizar un registro si existe, si no, entonces agregarlo**. Finalmente lo convertiré en stored procedure.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
INSERT CLIENTE([NIDTIPDOCUMENTO],[SNUMDOCUMENTO],[SNOMBRES],[SAPEPAT],[SAPEMAT],[SCORREO],[STELEF],[NESTADO],[SUSUREG]) 
                VALUES (1,'73129638','JEAN CARLOS','GARCIA','CHANGANO','JCARLOS@OYTLOOK.COM','55369899',1,'CPEREZ'),(2,'20123513124','JUAN','CASTRO','CHANGANO','JCARLOS@OYTLOOK.COM','55369899',1,'CPEREZ')

INSERT TIPO_DOCUMENTO([SDESTIPDOCUMENTO],[NESTADO],[SUSUREG]) VALUES('DNI',1,'CPEREZ')
INSERT TIPO_DOCUMENTO([SDESTIPDOCUMENTO],[NESTADO],[SUSUREG]) VALUES('RUC',1,'CPEREZ')
GO

MERGE CLIENTE AS C USING CLIENTE AS AUX
ON (C.NIDCLIENTE=AUX.NIDCLIENTE) 
    WHEN MATCHED AND C.NIDCLIENTE=3 THEN
        UPDATE
            SET C.SNOMBRES =  'JORGE'
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN
        INSERT (C.NIDTIPDOCUMENTO,C.SNUMDOCUMENTO,C.SNOMBRES,C.SAPEPAT,C.SAPEMAT,C.SCORREO,C.STELEF,C.NESTADO,C.SUSUREG)
            VALUES(1,'27867787','LUIS CARLOS','PRADA','BENAVIDES','@JBENAVIDES@GMAIL.COM','2341412423',1,'CMEJIA');
```

Al hacer ello me sale el siguiente error:
La lista de columnas de inserción de la instrucción MERGE no puede contener identificadores formados por varias partes. En su lugar, use identificadores formados por una sola parte.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Lo que dices y lo que intentas no se parece. Por ejemplo no entiendo `AND C.NIDCLIENTE=3` y `C.SNOMBRES =  'JORGE'` en la parte del `MATCHED`, pero no veo ningún `JORGE` en el insert. No veo que el intento sea muy serio.

Comment: es que fueron datos de prueba, luego lo voy a migrar a un stored procedure